# Cannot read property 'action' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm currently learning to create a chatbot that can give the weather (using nodejs and dialogflow), but I'm facing a problem for which I can not find solutions (I'm new to javascript). Every time I try to run my webhook with dialogflow, I get an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined". Apparently, it comes from "var action = req.body.result.action;". Here is an extract of the code :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const owmToken = ; //Token

const webhook = express();
webhook.set('port',9000); webhook.use(bodyParser.json());

webhook.listen(webhook.get('port'),function() {console.log('webhook démarré en',webhook.get('port'));});    
webhook.post('/webhook',function(req,res){
    var action = req.body.result.action;
        switch(action) {
            case 'interrogation_openweathermap': {
                var ville=
                req.body.result.parameters['ville'];
                request.get(
                    'http://api.openweathermap.com/data/2.5/?q='+ville+'&lang=fr&APPID='+owmToken,
                    function(error,response,body){
                        console.log(body);
                        var json = JSON.parse(body);
                        out = construireReponseMeteoDuJour(json,"Aujourd'hui", ville);
                        res.json(out);});
                    }break ;}

    })
```

I'm using NodeJs 8.11.2

The full error message :

```
{ responseId: '4f56ae2e-3415-4fd3-bcb0-57c76d5b9927',
  queryResult:
   { queryText: 'météo nancy',
     action: 'interrogation_openweathermap',
     parameters: { Ville: 'Nancy' },
     allRequiredParamsPresent: true,
     fulfillmentText: 'Désolé, mais je ne parviens pas à obtenir la météo de Nancy, veuillez réessayer plus tard !',
     fulfillmentMessages: [ [Object] ],
     intent:
      { name: 'projects/agentfr-d7830/agent/intents/d37c07f1-b639-48b3-b48a-f9f370843e6d',
        displayName: 'Demander_Météo' },
     intentDetectionConfidence: 0.89,
     diagnosticInfo: {},
     languageCode: 'fr' },
  originalDetectIntentRequest: { payload: {} },
  session: 'projects/agentfr-d7830/agent/sessions/104fd141-0b0a-37cf-2dd0-dbacc9552968' }
    > TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined
    >     at C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\index.js:18:30
    >     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    >     at next (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    >     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    >     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    >     at C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    >     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    >     at next (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    >     at C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    >     at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\webhook\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
```

Thank you for advice,

Comment: probably you forgot to add express [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser), you should post code main file where you creating server and setting middleware

Comment: print req.body and check the structure.

Comment: @ArifKhan - post that as the answer, since it looks like the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in comment, you missed to add body parser for urlencoded

```
webhook.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: you can print header in callback to see request Content-Type, something like `console.loge(req.get('Content-Type'));`

Comment: before `var action = req.body.result.action;`, you should print on console data `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: I just did it and test, but it's the same result. But now, I can see the API response with CMD

Comment: Can you paste what response you are abler to see on cmd

Comment: I past it in my first message

Comment: now everything is clear, you are using wrong key `action` use `queryResult`  like `var action = req.body.queryResult.action;`

Comment: Thanx. The problem is solved for "var action = req.body.queryResult.action". But now, I have the same issue with parameters that is undefined : "req.body.result.parameters['ville'];"

Answer (score 0):

Try printing 'req' . As this doesn't has the body attribute, req.body is undefined. Unfortunately it doesn't give an error like other languages that it has no attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For

> req.body.result.parameters['ville'];

You may use

> req.body.queryResult.parameters.Ville

Comment: I try it, but i get the same result :( Can I try something like queryParam or queryParameters ?

Comment: Have you noticed the Caps letter on "Ville"?
+ You must use req.body.queryResult.Ville

Comment: Your response data is all contained in an object which is called "queryResult", so everytime that you need something in it, you have to use "req.body.queryResult.sthing"